# using javascript variables

Tags: javascript, arcgis

I"m trying to teach my self coding for some mapping work, and I cannot seem to wrap my head around this.

I have a JavaScript function that is called from a button:
This code connects my button using DOJO:

```
on(dom.byId("metro"), "change", updateLayerVisibility);
```

The following code correctly turns my layer off (*metro* is defined elsewhere)

```
function updateLayerVisibility(){

metro.setVisibility(false);
  }
```

However if i try to use a variable I get an error that "test.setvisiblity is not a function"

```
function updateLayerVisibility(){
var test = "metro";
test.setVisibility(false);
}
```

So my question is what is the difference between these two?  why isn't "metro" substituted for "test"? If its because the variable is a string, what should it be converted to.

Thanks (and sorry for the strange question)

Comment: Yes, it is because `test` is a string. You could do `test = metro;` but at thhat point, why use a variable at all?

Comment: I want to use the same function to turn off many layers.

Answer (score 1):

In your above example, `test` is just a string and strings don't have a method named `setVisibility`. However a `metro` object (apparently) does.

The methods available to strings can be seen here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Methods

Comment: OK, how would I programmatically change "test" to "metro" and have it work? For example, I tried 
'var text = test + ".setVisibility(False);
 text'

which didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

`metro` is an identifier. In that context it is a *variable*. It will have a value, in this case, that value is an object with a property `setVisibility` that has (in turn) a value that is a function.

`test` is also an identifier and a variable. It has a value, which is the *string* `"metro"`. The string has no connection to the variable `metro` and it doesn't have a `setVisibility` property.

Comment: Great answer.  How would i connect 'test' to the variable 'metro' ?.

Answer (score 1):

The key part of your question is where you say "metro is defined elsewhere".  As already suggested by others, your metro object is not just a string with a value (as your test object is) but a reference to a particular type of object which has particular functions such as setVisibility.

I think I see what you want to do: programmatically turn individual layers on and off.  If you know the layer ID then you can get a reference to a layer using:

```
var layer = map.getLayer(id);
```

(where `map` is your reference to the ArcGIS map object and `id` is the string name of the layer to return.  So if you had a layer with the id "metro" you would get it with:

```
var layer = map.getLayer("metro");
```

Here you can substitute the string passed in to the getLayer method for any other string value that represents the id of a layer you want.

Once you've got your layer object you can then set it's visibility in the same way as you were with the metro layer reference:

```
layer.setVisibility(false);
```

Hope this helps!